# DataSet showing some other data's while Previewing on Winforms Devexpress

Tags: winforms, ms-access, devexpress

My MS Access Database table consist of some data's. I add that table into DataSet of Winforms Devexpress. While retrieving the data's one column(Amount Paid) getting wrong data's. help to recover this problem.
1st image showing my MS Access Database Table and 2nd image showing DataSet table in Winform Devexpress

This is the SQL Query I used to create the query table in MS Access Database

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, 
      (SELECT PaymentTerms FROM PSD_customerPaymentTerms WHERE PSD_customerPaymentTerms.PTId = NewInvoice_1.Terms) AS Terms, 
      InvoiceDate, 
      OurQuote, 
      (SELECT FirstName FROM Employee WHERE Employee.EmployeeId = NewInvoice_1.SalesPerson) AS SalesPerson, 
      (SELECT CustomerName FROM Customer WHERE Customer.CustomerId = NewInvoice_1.CustomerName) AS CustomerName, 
      OrderNumber, 
      GrandTotal,  
      (SELECT SUM(PaymentAmount) FROM Payment_Receipt WHERE Payment_Receipt.InvoiceNumber=NewInvoice_1.InvoiceNumber) AS AmountPaid, 
      GrandTotal-IIf(AmountPaid Is Null,0,AmountPaid) AS AmountDue
FROM NewInvoice_1;
```

1st Image
[image]

2nd Image
[image]

Comment: Please, show us the code where you load the data into the DataTable and how do you make the binding in the grid.

Comment: Hi @mnieto, I update my question kindly verify it.

Comment: For vote downers can you tel why you vote down this issue ? next time i will correct it.

Comment: Likely it's because you ain't providing the information required to help.

Comment: Thankyou next time I will provide all information @Crono

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the binding for the AmountPaid column isn't set properly. I suggest you start by checking the column's `FieldName` property. If it's set correctly then your problem is likely an event that changes the cell text or some code changing the value in the underlying datasource at runtime.

If you can't find anything there, I suggest you share some code so that you can get more help.

Comment: Unfortunately your updated answer only shows the query you are executing on the database, not how the result is bound to the grid.

Comment: In Winforms if I need any tables to use means, first I add that table to DataSet then I use that table fields into form controls or grid by add Data Source.

Comment: I suggest that you quit using wizards and learn how binding works because I'm sure problem is there. Unfortunately that is all the help I or anyone can give you at this point.